# I'm wondering if there is any Java 8 instruction that allows me to retrieve the complete message received in a SOAP web service response

Tags: web-services, soap, java-8, wsdl, weblogic

I'm facing an issue while replicating a Java 8 SOAP web service to replace one in a WebLogic production environment. I've successfully ensured that the WSDL contract matches exactly with the production version, adjusting the location address to my local environment. Everything appears identical, from the XML generated for the request to the service response, when compared to the production service.

```
However, when attempting to consume the service from a Delphi system by simply changing the path, the connection is not established. On the web service side, I'm encountering the following error:

css

Dec 21, 2023 12:19:42 PM com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler createResponse
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ws.AccederWSService_AccederWSSoapPortImpl.getPaciente(AccederWSService_AccederWSSoapPortImpl.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    ...

At the line 'ws.AccederWSService_AccederWSSoapPortImpl.getPaciente(AccederWSService_AccederWSSoapPortImpl.java:22),' I am attempting to retrieve values from the input of the web service.

And this is the error that Delphi throws:

markdown

---------------------------
Debugger Exception Notification
---------------------------
Project PFAR_REC_INDIVIDUAL.exe raised exception class ERemotableException with message 'java.lang.NullPointerException'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.
---------------------------
OK   Help   
---------------------------

The web service works normally in other tools like SOAP UI.

I'm wondering if there is any Java 8 instruction that allows me to retrieve the complete message received in a web service response, including all information. I'm looking for a way to better analyze the error I'm experiencing.

I'm using the javax.jws.WebService libraries.

Additionally, does anyone have knowledge of any instructions that would allow me to analyze the information I'm receiving to better understand the error? Any insights into what might be hindering the connection with the new web service despite the WSDL being identical to the production service?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions!
```

Comment: Please format the question to improve readability

Comment: Please add more details. Does the same Delphi application work well with the production system SOAP service? Have you verified  that it sends exactly the same request?